# Accidentally Uninstalled SATA Driver from XP

Tags: windows-xp, sata, slipstream

I was uninstalling a VIA RAID/SATA utility and accidentally removed the SATA driver in the process.  Once I restarted the computer and the uninstall took effect, XP no longer had the SATA driver in order for it to load.  I get a BSOD.

I know I can reinstall XP with the SATA drivers slipstreamed.  Is there a way to reinstall the SATA driver without reinstalling XP altogether?  Thanks.

EDIT: I decided to just restore a disk image of the partition.  Problem solved.

Comment: Have you looked at these? http://superuser.com/questions/232093/how-can-i-install-xp-on-a-sata-drive-without-having-a-floppy-drive-for-the-drive
http://superuser.com/questions/293933/asus-sata-drivers-for-win-xp-repair

Answer (score 0):

Answered by OP

> I decided to just restore a disk image of the partition. Problem
>   solved.